# Spring x509 store anonymous users CN

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, x509

I have a spring boot application that I'm securing with spring x509 and I'm using two way SSL certs with any clients that want to use my API. The API will be available to any clients with valid certs, however I want to ensure that I can retrieve the clients cert details for auditing purposes. I have two potential solutions but there is a problem with each.

Firstly I could configure my security settings with

```
http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().anonymous().and().x509();
```

This will ensure that any client who holds a valid cert can access the API however because users are anonymous whenever I get the x509Certificate object it's empty.

```
((X509Certificate) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials()).getIssuerDN().getName()
```

The other option is to have my security settings as below and implement a very simple UserDetailsService.

```
http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().x509().userDetailsService(myUserService);
```

The user service I've implemented is:

```
@Service
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
         return new User(username,"N/A", Arrays.asList(() -> "ROLE_SSL"));
    }

}
```

This then ensures that spring stores all the clients cert details and can be retrieved using the same call I listed earlier. However I don't like the fact that I'm forced to implement such a simple userDetailsService and include a role that isn't necessary. I don't need to store user details on the spring boot app or retrieve anything from a datastore using a userdetailsservice so I was hoping there would be a simpler way to get hold of the users x509 cert details. Is there an easier way I could achieve this, perhaps I'm missing a call in the http fluent security calls?

Comment: use getIssuerX500Principal() instead of getIssuerDN(). Not sure this will solve your problem but as per javadoc getIssuerDN() is Denigrated

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however its the SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials() that is empty. However if I do decide to use the UserDetailsSerivce ill make sure to add the changes you recommended.